# C# Local variables and Multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

How do I un-threadproof my local variables so my threads can access variabes  inside my main()

Comment: is this enough to explain your problem ? no, it is not

Answer (score 2):

You neeed to make the local variables `static` to the class.

For example, change this:

```
public class Hello1
{
   public static void Main()
   {
     string kiaora = "Hello, World!";

     System.Console.WriteLine(kiaora);
   }
}
```

to:

```
public class Hello1
{
   public static readonly string kiaora = "Hello, World!";
   public static void Main()
   {
     System.Console.WriteLine(kiaora);
   }
}
```

Then, your "threads" can access `Hello1.kiora` to get a greeting.